# Android arm instructions how to turn to x86 instructions

Tags: android, arm, hook, android-x86

For example, the arm directive "LDR PC, [pc, -#4]" on the x86 corresponding instructions should be how to write? Seeking method

Comment: Your question is way too broad.  It is almost like 'how to write code?'.  There maybe multiple ways to translate one instruction.  Also, there may be no equivalent.  Most importantly, groups of instructions will have a translation that is more efficient (and direct).

Comment: are you trying to convert a whole program?  Google static binary translation.  It is a lot of work, but possible, far better to translate to C then let the compiler remove the dead code than from one instruction set to another.  Runtime instruction set simulation is an alternative, or even better just re-compile the source to the different target.